# Laravel 5.3 login with newly created user (from Socialite)

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, laravel-5.3

I need such logic:
1) User login's from facebook or google+
2) If it's new user credentials i create new user and logins him
3) If it's old user i login him.

I have strange problem - in 2) User creates, but after it it's redirecting to login page. If i make another try(user already created in 2), all ok and user redirecting to home page( successfuly logins).

Why it's happens and what i must to fix?

My app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Redirect the user to the GitHub authentication page.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function redirectToProvider($type)
{
    return \Socialite::driver($type)->redirect();
}

/**
 * Obtain the user information from GitHub.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function handleProviderCallback($type)
{
    $userRepository=new \App\Repositories\UserRepository;
    $user=$userRepository->loginOrCreate($type,\Socialite::driver($type)->user());
    return redirect()->to('/home');

}
}
```

My routes/web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/', 'UserController@show');
Route::get('auth/redirect/{type}', 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('auth/callback/{type}', 'Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
Route::post('/lang', 'HomeController@postChangeLanguage');
   Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

My app/Repositories/UserRepository.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Repositories;

use App\User;
use App\UserAuth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;
use Mockery\CountValidator\Exception;

class UserRepository
{
/**
 * @param $userData
 * @return static
 */

public function loginOrCreate($type, $oauthUser)
{
    $auth = UserAuth::where('type', $type)
        ->where('_id', $oauthUser->getId())
        ->get();


    if (!$auth->isEmpty()) {
        foreach ($auth as $aut) {
            $user = User::where('id', $aut->user_id)->first();

            Auth::login($user, true);
            return $user;
        }
    } else {
        // user not found
        //creating new user

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $oauthUser->getName();
        $user->email = $oauthUser->getEmail();
        $user->autocreated = 1;
        $user->password = 'autocreated';
        $user->remember_token = 'autocreated';
        //    $user->avatar= $oauthUser->getAvatar();
        if (!$user->save()
        ) {
            throw new \Exception('Can not create user');
        }
        echo('user created');
        try {
            $userAuth = new UserAuth();

            $userAuth->type = $type;
            $userAuth->token = $oauthUser->token;
            $userAuth->refreshToken = $oauthUser->refreshToken;
            $userAuth->tokenSecret = '';
            $userAuth->_id = $oauthUser->getId();
            $userAuth->nickname = $oauthUser->getNickname() ? $oauthUser->getNickname() : $oauthUser->getName();
            $userAuth->name = $oauthUser->getName();
            $userAuth->email = $oauthUser->getEmail();
            $userAuth->avatar = $oauthUser->getAvatar();
            $userAuth->expiresIn = $oauthUser->expiresIn ? $oauthUser->expiresIn : 0;
            $userAuth->meta = '';//print_r($userAuth, true);
            $userAuth->user_id = $user->id;


            $userAuth->save();
        } catch (QueryException $e) {
            echo('exc');
            echo($e->getMessage());
            $user->delete();
            throw $e;

        }

        $user = User::where('id', $user->id)->first();

        Auth::login($user, true);

        return $user;

    }

}


}
```